# Arguments of function in and out of a class are different

Tags: python

I apologize, I still don't entirely understand classes in python. Anyway, I have a program like this:

```
class foo(args):
    def __init__(self):
         #stuff
         self.func(self, var)
    def func(self, var):
         return things(self, var)
def things(self, var):
    ##some stuff
```

My problem is that when I run this It says I am giving 3 arguments when it asks for 2. When I change things by getting rid of the self.func and putting func(self, var) instead, it says I am giving one variable too few. What is going on? Thanks in advance.

**EDIT:** Thanks for the answer cppcoder, but that doesn't help, because it just spits back saying there are too few args. I used a static variable instead of a function.

Comment: Make that call in your init `self.func(var)`.  `func` is a bound method, `self` is implicitly provided as the first argument.

Answer (score 1):

`self` is an implicit argument and you need not provide it while invoking the function.
You can invoke as `func(var)`

You can read about this in [What is the purpose of self?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2709821/python-self-explained)